# Add Jquery from standard style in wordpress custom theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the used the following code in the front page of Custom theme but want to improve on how to load jquery. Please suggest me with cool answers

/assets/js/jquery.min.js'>

/assets/js/bootstrap.js'>

/assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js'>

/assets/js/custom-scripts.js'>

Answer (score 0):

Please check WP way to include scripts

```
function ax_enqueue_style() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom.css' );
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ax_enqueue_style' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to load jQuery is to declare it as a dependency when you enqueue your custom scripts. That way if plugins are using jQuery you wont load it again. Assuming all your plugins follow best practices too.

in your case it would look like:

```
//functions.php
function my_theme_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'), '0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-mixitup', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js', array('jquery'), '0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom-scripts', array('jquery'), '0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Wordpress recognizes the handle 'jquery' and loads the latest stable version in the correct order.

Note: the '0' is the version number and can be any number you choose. Update it at any time ex '0.1' and it will force the user's browser to re-download cached files.

References:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/